# Why does the security.ubuntu.com repository exist?

Tags: security, repository, software-sources, add-apt-repository, official-repositories

Looking at the contends of the /etc/apt/sources.list file two repositories are listed:

archive.ubuntu.com and security.ubuntu.com

At first I thought that the security repository only contains security updates but it seems like it contains every other directory as well( i.e. -proposed, -updates, and so on).

Is this just a backup copy of the archive? If so, why is it named 'security'?

Why does it exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is addressed in [the Security Team FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ#What_repositories_and_pockets_should_I_use_to_make_sure_my_systems_are_up_to_date.3F):

> #### What repositories and pockets should I use to make sure my systems are up to date?
>
> - By default, Ubuntu systems have both the `security` and `updates` pockets enabled. Systems configured to use only the `security` pocket
>   are also supported.
> - While packages are copied from `security` to `updates` frequently, it is recommended that systems always have the `security` pocket
>   enabled, and use `security.ubuntu.com` for this pocket. For all other
>   pockets feel free to use `archive.ubuntu.com` or an [archive
>   mirror](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors). This
>   combination will ensure you are able to download important updates
>   immediately while taking advantage of the mirror network or
>   `archive.ubuntu.com` for all other downloads. Ubuntu systems are
>   configured in this manner by default.

The security.ubuntu.com alias exists so that you can freely use mirrors for regular software installation and updates, while being assured of receiving timely security updates even if the mirror is not updated, goes down or has other problems.

Comment: That makes sense. But I thought that this is what the -security directory is intended for within the archive repository. Whats the point of having the same security updates in two repositories?

Comment: It's what I said in the last paragraph: "so that you can freely use mirrors for regular software installation and updates, while being assured of receiving timely security updates even if the mirror ... has problems"